# c# stop button for beep sound

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio

I created a simple `C#` app that uses the beep console. I want to add a stop button to stop the beeping, but once the app starts to run it doesnt let me hit a close/button button. Below is the code i have.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int int1, int2, hours;

    int1 = int.Parse(txtbox1.Text);
    int2 = int.Parse(txtbox2.Text);

    hours = ((60 / int1) * int2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= hours; i++)
    {
        Console.Beep();
        Thread.Sleep(int1 * 60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a Timer() to your Form and set its Interval() property.  Handle the Tick() event and Beep() from there.  You can start and stop the Timer with Start() and Stop().

Comment: @Idle_Mind, that's a good idea, but you should spend a few more seconds and make it an answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the thought Kirk.  I was supposed to be heading out the door so I just wrote it up super quick!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you execute `button1_Click` in the GUI thread. When you call this method the thread will be stuck there for *quite some time* because you make it sleep.

If you remove `Thread.Sleep(int1*60000);` you will notice that your application is unresponsive until it is done beeping.

You should try to use a `Timer` instead. Something like this should work (this is based on the [`Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)):

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

And set it up

```
timer.Tick += OnTick;
timer.Interval = int1 * 60000;
...


private void OnTick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
   Console.Beep();     
}
```

In your buttonclick you are now able to start and stop the timer:

```
timer.Start();
```

or

```
timer.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a timer in this case, the reason why you can't close the form is because you are calling a sleep on the form thread from what I understand. Calling a sleep on the form thread will give the impression the app has crashed.

Here is a quick sample code I built in c#, it will beep the console at the time given. I hope it helps.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_dosomething);
        timer1.Interval = 60000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    void timer_dosomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Beep();
    }
```